# How could I send message of many fields with c++ grpc stream?

Tags: c++, stream, protocol-buffers, grpc

Suppose the message that I need to send from server to client is like this:

```
message BatchReply {
    bytes data = 1;
    repeated int32 shape = 2;
    string dtype = 3;
    repeated int64 labels = 4;
}
```

Here `shape`/`dtype` are only small variables and can be represented with a few int space, while `data`/`labels` are large memory buffers that can takes as much as 1G memory.

I am trying to send this message with stream:

```
service ImageService {
    rpc get_batch (BatchRequest) returns (stream BatchReply) {}
}
```

My question is that the examples I could find to send message through stream are all about messages with only one field in the message struct, such as:

```
service TransferFile {
    rpc Upload(stream Chunk) returns (Reply) {}
}
message Chunk {
    bytes buffer = 1; // here is only on field of buffer, what if there is a field of int val = 2; ?
}
```

What if there are two fields in the struct of `Chunk`. Do I need to call `set_val()` each time when I call `set_buffer()` during the same stream feeding process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just send a message with multiple fields over grpc. That is the advantage of using protobuf.

I do not know if the transmission layer you are using is able to deal with such a large message as you are specifying. You could test that. If this does not work you can use the example you give of `TransferFile`.

When looking at `Chunk` I get the impression that they are sending segments of the whole data. On the other side they then reconstruct the segments into the complete set. The type used for `Chunk` is bytes. Those are just raw bytes and can represent anything you would like.

To send your `BatchReply` in chunks you can use the following steps:

1. Set the data in a `BatchReply` object.
2. Serialize the object to a byte array.
3. Set a chunk of the byte array in a `Chunk` object. For example 100 bytes each time.
4. Send the `Chunk` object using the `TransferFile` interface.
5. Repeat the process from step 3. until you reach the end of the byte array.

On the reception side you concatenate the chunks into one array and deserialize the array back to a `BatchReply` object.

Comment: Thanks for replying, to make sure I got your idea: first I add the data into `BatchReply`, then I serialize them with protobuf api, after that I add the serialized struct as bytes to `Chunk` and send it through stream. Lastly, I received it at client side, and then deserialize it to original structure and parse it, am I correct ?

Comment: BTW, do you recommend me use stream or unary calls to transmit the serialized data please ?

Comment: Yes that is the process. But only if you can not send the BatchReply in one go. I have not sufficient knowledge about streams to judge between streams or unary calls.