# How to pass big amount of data(unknown size, minimum 10GB) using gRPC

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

From a source I am getting stream data which size will not be known before the final processing, but the minimum is 10 GB. I have to send this large amount of data using `gRPC`.

Need to mention here, this `large amount data` will be passed through the `gRPC` while the processing of the `streaming` is done. In this step, I have thought to store all the value in a `vector`.

###### Regarding sending large amount of data I have tried to get idea and found:

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68644134/how-to-split-long-messages-into-short-messages-in-grpc-c) where it is mentioned not to pass large data using `gRPC`. Here, mentioned to use any other message protocol where I have limitation to use something else rather than `gRPC`(at least till today).
- [From this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60538700/how-could-i-send-message-of-many-fields-with-c-grpc-stream) I have tried to know how `chunk message` can be sent but I am not sure is it related to my problem or not.
- [First post](https://jbrandhorst.com/post/grpc-binary-blob-stream/) where I have found a blog to stream data using `go` language.
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54334419/10634362) the presentation using `python` language of [this post](https://jbrandhorst.com/post/grpc-binary-blob-stream/). But it is also incomplete.
- [gRPC example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/cpp/route_guide) could be a good start bt cannot decode due to lack of C++ knowledge

### From there, a huge Update I have done in the question. But the main theme of the question is not changed

###### What I have done so far and some points about my project. The [github repo is available here](https://github.com/atifkarim/gRPC_CPP_CMake/tree/streaming_chunk).

- A `Unary rpc` is present in the project
- I know that my new `Bi directional rpc` will take some time. I want that the `Unary rpc` will not wait for the completion of the `Bi directional rpc`. Right now I am thinking in a  `synchronous way` where `Unary rpc` is waiting to pass it's `status` for the streaming one completion.
- I am avoiding the unnecessary lines in `C++ code`. But giving whole `proto` files
- `big_data.proto`

```sh
syntax = "proto3";

package demo_grpc;

message Large_Data {
    repeated int32 large_data_collection = 1 [packed=true];
    int32 data_chunk_number = 2;
}
```

- `addressbook.proto`

```sh
syntax = "proto3";

package demo_grpc;

import "myproto/big_data.proto";

message S_Response {
    string name     = 1;
    string street   = 2;
    string zip      = 3;
    string city     = 4;
    string country  = 5;

    int32 double_init_val = 6;
}

message C_Request {
    uint32 choose_area = 1;
    string name = 2;
    int32 init_val = 3;
}

service AddressBook {
    rpc GetAddress(C_Request) returns (S_Response) {}

    rpc Stream_Chunk_Service(stream Large_Data) returns (stream Large_Data) {}
}
```

- `client.cpp`

```cpp
#include <big_data.pb.h>
#include <addressbook.grpc.pb.h>

#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include <grpcpp/create_channel.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

// This function prompts the user to set value for the required area
void Client_Request(demo_grpc::C_Request &request_)
{
// do processing for unary rpc. Intentionally avoided here
}

// According to Client Request this function display the value of protobuf message
void Server_Response(demo_grpc::C_Request &request_, const demo_grpc::S_Response &response_)
{
// do processing for unary rpc. Intentionally avoided here
}

// following function make large vector and then chunk to send via stream from client to server
void Stream_Data_Chunk_Request(demo_grpc::Large_Data &request_,
                               demo_grpc::Large_Data &response_,
                               uint64_t preferred_chunk_size_in_kibyte)
{
    // A dummy vector which in real case will be the large data set's container
    std::vector<int32_t> large_vector;

    // irerate it now for 1024*10 times
    for(int64_t i = 0; i < 1024 * 10; i++)
    {
        large_vector.push_back(1);
    }

    uint64_t preferred_chunk_size_in_kibyte_holds_integer_num = 0; // 1 chunk how many intger will contain that num will come here

    // total chunk number will be updated here
    uint32_t total_chunk = total_chunk_counter(large_vector.size(), preferred_chunk_size_in_kibyte, preferred_chunk_size_in_kibyte_holds_integer_num);

    // A temp counter to trace the index of the large_vector
    int32_t temp_count = 0;

    // loop will start if the total num of chunk is greater than 0. After each iteration total_chunk will be decremented
    while(total_chunk > 0)
    {
        for (int64_t i = temp_count * preferred_chunk_size_in_kibyte_holds_integer_num; i < preferred_chunk_size_in_kibyte_holds_integer_num + temp_count * preferred_chunk_size_in_kibyte_holds_integer_num; i++)
        {
            // the repeated field large_data_collection is taking value from the large_vector
            request_.add_large_data_collection(large_vector[i]);
        }
        temp_count++;
        total_chunk--;

        std::string ip_address = "localhost:50051";
        auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel(ip_address, grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials());
        std::unique_ptr<demo_grpc::AddressBook::Stub> stub = demo_grpc::AddressBook::NewStub(channel);

        grpc::ClientContext context;
        std::shared_ptr<::grpc::ClientReaderWriter< ::demo_grpc::Large_Data, ::demo_grpc::Large_Data> > stream(stub->Stream_Chunk_Service(&context));

        // While the size of each chunk is eached then this repeated field is cleared. I am not sure before this
        // value can be transfered to server or not. But my assumption is saying that it should be done
        request_.clear_large_data_collection();
    }

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string client_address = "localhost:50051";
    std::cout << "Address of client: " << client_address << std::endl;

    // The following part for the Unary RPC
    demo_grpc::C_Request query;
    demo_grpc::S_Response result;
    Client_Request(query);

    // This part for the streaming chunk data (Bi directional Stream RPC)
    demo_grpc::Large_Data stream_chunk_request_;
    demo_grpc::Large_Data stream_chunk_response_;
    uint64_t preferred_chunk_size_in_kibyte = 64;
    Stream_Data_Chunk_Request(stream_chunk_request_, stream_chunk_response_, preferred_chunk_size_in_kibyte);

    // Call
    auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel(client_address, grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials());
    std::unique_ptr<demo_grpc::AddressBook::Stub> stub = demo_grpc::AddressBook::NewStub(channel);
    grpc::ClientContext context;
    grpc::Status status = stub->GetAddress(&context, query, &result);

    // the following status is for unary rpc as far I have understood the structure
    if (status.ok())
    {
        Server_Response(query, result);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << status.error_message() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

- `heper function total_chunk_counter`

```cpp
#include <cmath>
uint32_t total_chunk_counter(uint64_t num_of_container_content,
                             uint64_t preferred_chunk_size_in_kibyte,
                             uint64_t &preferred_chunk_size_in_kibyte_holds_integer_num)
{
    uint64_t cotainer_size_in_kibyte = (32ULL * num_of_container_content) / 1024;
    preferred_chunk_size_in_kibyte_holds_integer_num = (num_of_container_content * preferred_chunk_size_in_kibyte) / cotainer_size_in_kibyte;

    float total_chunk = static_cast<float>(num_of_container_content) / preferred_chunk_size_in_kibyte_holds_integer_num;
    return std::ceil(total_chunk);
}
```

- `server.cpp` which is totally incomplete

```cpp
#include <myproto/big_data.pb.h>
#include <myproto/addressbook.grpc.pb.h>

#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include <grpcpp/server_builder.h>

#include <iostream>

class AddressBookService final : public demo_grpc::AddressBook::Service {
    public:
        virtual ::grpc::Status GetAddress(::grpc::ServerContext* context, const ::demo_grpc::C_Request* request, ::demo_grpc::S_Response* response)
        {
            switch (request->choose_area())
            {
             // do processing for unary rpc. Intentionally avoided here
            std::cout << "Information of " << request->choose_area() << " is sent to Client" << std::endl;
            return grpc::Status::OK;
            }


    // Bi-directional streaming chunk data
    virtual ::grpc::Status Stream_Chunk_Service(::grpc::ServerContext* context, ::grpc::ServerReaderWriter< ::demo_grpc::Large_Data, ::demo_grpc::Large_Data>* stream)
    {
        // stream->Large_Data;
        return grpc::Status::OK;
    }
};

void RunServer()
{
    std::cout << "grpc Version: " << grpc::Version() << std::endl;
    std::string server_address = "localhost:50051";
    std::cout << "Address of server: " << server_address << std::endl;

    grpc::ServerBuilder builder;
    builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());

    AddressBookService my_service;
    builder.RegisterService(&my_service);

    std::unique_ptr<grpc::Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());
    server->Wait();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    RunServer();
    return 0;
}
```

##### In summary my desire

- I need to pass the content of `large_vector` with the `repeated field large_data_collection` of message `Large_Data`. I should `chunk` the size of the `large_vector` and populate the `repeated field large_data_collection` with that `chunk size`
- In server side all `chunk` will be concatenate by keeping the exact order of the `large_vector`. Some processing will be done on them (eg: `double the value of each index`). Then again whole data will be sent to the `client` as a `chunk stream`
- Would be great if the present `unary rpc` don't wait for the completion of the `bi-directional rpc`

Solution with example would be really helpful. Advance thanks. The [github repo is available here](https://github.com/atifkarim/gRPC_CPP_CMake/tree/streaming_chunk).

Comment: Obvioulsy if the maximum size is 2GB and you have at least 10GB, you have to send at least 5 chucks of data! But I think a chuck size like 64KB might be a better compromise.

Comment: @Phil1970 can you kindly provide me an example in c++ including proto file?  I am not getting the idea of this `chunk`.

Comment: @Phil1970 I am confused till now about 3 things. (1) How the message will be written for that chunk? Do i use a `repeated int32 ` field(i know that all data getting from the source will be int32 type). (2) What will be the way( i mean here syntax) of server & client to deal with stream message?  3/ I have another `unary rpc` is running & it will. May I call this `stream..  Chunk service` with that `unary` without hampering it? I know stream will take some time but want to know that unary can do it operation without waiting or not?

Comment: @Phil1970 I have tried to update my approach. Can you kindly take a look? I am not getting the correct way to pass the data in a `chunk stream`. Also in the `server side` cannot get the idea what to do.

Comment: Finally, I have solved the issue. As soon as possible will submit the answer.

Comment: Hi, @davidA I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to lots of personal issue, I am very late to post the answer of my problem. By the way, I have achieved my solution in the following way. A little bit summary of my solution:

- I have tried to pass a big amount of data, for this I have chosen a big size of vector whose size will be varied
- I have calculated the number of sample in vector, chose a size for the chunk as well as calculated how many integers will be passed by each chunk
- Finally, passed the data one by one with respect to number of chunk
- One limitation I have chosen that size of chunk should be 64 or it's multiple.
- A complete solution is available in my [git repo](https://github.com/atifkarim/gRPC_CPP_CMake/commit/e12f5f00703836472eb2c2ceab89621b33da5341). I have linked here only the commit of the merge request

#### Proto message

```
// Proto file to send large amount of data using stream

syntax = "proto3";

package demo_grpc;

message Streaming
{
    repeated int32 data_collection = 1 [packed=true];
    int32 index = 2;
}

// Follwoing messages will be used for Bi-directional streaming (chunk data)

// Client side message
message Large_Data_Request {
    repeated int32 chunk_data_client_request = 1 [packed=true]; // Data container where chunk data will be stored to pass as stream from client to server
    uint32 client_data_stream_size = 2; // This will be the size of the whole data stream from client to server (Eg: Size of a vector. vec.size())
    uint32 chunk_data_length = 3; // Number of data samples in each chunk
    uint32 required_chunk = 4; // Number of chunk to complete the Streaming
    string name = 5; // Name name of the data stream
}

// Server side message
message Large_Data_Response {
    repeated int32 chunk_data_server_response = 1 [packed=true]; // Data container to be used to do stream operation from server to client
    int32 server_data_stream_size = 2; // This will be the size of the whole data stream from server to client (Eg: Size of a vector. vec.size())
}
```

#### Client side request to send stream data

```cpp
#include "client_zone.h"

// Calculates the number of chunk
/**
 * \param [in] data_size Total size of given/provided data which will be passed as chunk. Eg: myvec.size()
 * \param [in] chunk_size Chunk size in KiloByte. This chunk size will be given by the user. Right now less than 64 KB is not allowed
 * \param [in] sample Data sample in each chunk
 */
void grpc_client::get_chunk_number(uint64_t data_size,
                                   uint64_t chunk_size,
                                   uint64_t &sample,
                                   uint32_t &total_chunk)
{
    // Each integer size is 4 Byte. That's why N integer size will be N * 4 bit
    // To convert this into KB we have to divide the prior result with 1024. Eg: (vector.size() * 4) / 1024
    uint64_t data_size_kb = (4ULL * data_size) / 1024;

    float total_chunk_intermediate = static_cast<float>(data_size) / sample;
    total_chunk = std::ceil(total_chunk_intermediate);
}

// After producing large data set it passes them & get response from server as chunk
void grpc_client::data_chunk_stream_request()
{
    demo_grpc::Large_Data_Request request_;
    demo_grpc::Large_Data_Response response_;

    // This chunk size will be provided by the user. It will not be greater than 4 MB and will be provided in KB unit.
    // Eg: If you want to provide a chunk size of 3 MB you have to provide 3072 (3MB = 3 * 1024 KB)
    // Also, this value will be a multiple of 64. That means at least a chunk size should be provided which can carry
    // 64 KB data
    uint64_t chunk_size;
    std::cout << std:: endl << "Provide chunk size (KB). Not more than 4 MB. Will be multiple of 64: ";
    std::cin >> chunk_size;

    if (static_cast<float>(chunk_size) / 1024 > 4)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Chunk size is > 4 MB. Message field of protobuf is limited to 4 MB");
    }
    if (chunk_size % 64 != 0)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Please provide chunk size in multiple of 64 otherwise Number of chunk will be fractional");
    }

    // This vector is the container to hold dummy data created in client side
    std::vector<int32_t> dummy_data_set;

    // This is the size of the vector which will be chose by customer
    uint32_t vector_size;

    std::cout << "Dummy data will be create in client side. Please provide a size of vector: ";
    std::cin >> vector_size;
    for(int64_t i = 0; i < vector_size; i++)
    {
        dummy_data_set.push_back(2);
    }

    // Number of data in each chunk. Each integer is 4 byte. If chunk size is 64 KB that means "sample" will be number of
    // Integers resides in this each chunk size.
    // Convert this 64 KB to byte = 64 * 1024 Byte.
    // 4 byte is taken by 1 integer, so, 64 * 1024 bytes is taken by (64*1024)/4 integer
    uint64_t sample = (chunk_size * 1024)/4;

    // Number of chunk to transfer whole data set (here, dummy_data_set)
    uint32_t total_chunk = 0;

    get_chunk_number(dummy_data_set.size(), chunk_size, sample, total_chunk);

    // Proto Buffer message is preparing to pass to Server
    request_.set_chunk_data_length(sample);
    request_.set_client_data_stream_size(dummy_data_set.size());
    request_.set_required_chunk(total_chunk);
    request_.set_name(detected_area_name);

    grpc::ClientContext context;
    std::shared_ptr<::grpc::ClientReaderWriter< ::demo_grpc::Large_Data_Request, ::demo_grpc::Large_Data_Response> > stream(stub->Stream_Chunk_Service(&context));

    int32_t temp_count = 0;
    while(total_chunk > 0)
    {
        for (int64_t i = temp_count * sample; i < sample + temp_count * sample; i++)
        {
            // This condition checks the iteration number with the vector data size of the client
            // if client data size has reached then writing will be stopped
            if (i < dummy_data_set.size())
            {
                request_.add_chunk_data_client_request(dummy_data_set[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        temp_count++;
        total_chunk--;

        stream->Write(request_);

        // message field will be cleared after passing one chunk. It provides a fresh repeated field in the next iteration to pass a new chunk
        request_.clear_chunk_data_client_request();
    }

    stream->WritesDone();

    // Reading chunk response from server
    std::vector<int32_t> dummy_final_data_set;

    // This variable checks data size of client during read back from server
    uint32_t client_track_data_size_before_reading = 0;

    while (stream->Read(&response_))
    {
        for(int64_t i = 0; i < request_.chunk_data_length(); i++)
        {
            if (client_track_data_size_before_reading < dummy_data_set.size())
            {
                dummy_final_data_set.push_back(response_.chunk_data_server_response(i));
                client_track_data_size_before_reading++;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    grpc::Status status = stream->Finish();

    if (status.ok())
    {
        if (dummy_final_data_set.size() == response_.server_data_stream_size() | dummy_final_data_set.size() < response_.server_data_stream_size())
        {
            std::cout << "Server successfully has sent all data" << std::endl;
        }

    }
    else
        std::cout << "!!!!! Server is Failed to Stream !!!!!" << std::endl;
}
```

#### Server side response to return steam data after processing

```cpp
/*
This is the service response algorithm from server to pass
stream data using chunk
*/

#include <numeric>

void Data_Chunk_Stream_Response(::grpc::ServerReaderWriter< ::demo_grpc::Large_Data_Response, ::demo_grpc::Large_Data_Request>* stream)
{
    // Instance of request and response from client & server respectively
    demo_grpc::Large_Data_Request request;
    demo_grpc::Large_Data_Response response;

    // This vector will hold all data which will be transferred from client platform
    std::vector<int32_t> server_dummy_data_set;

    // This variable will track what is the size of the data which is passed from client
    uint32_t server_track_client_data_size_before_reading = 0;

    // Read operation
    while (stream->Read(&request))
    {
        // Iterate till the chunk data length is reached
        for(int64_t i = 0; i < request.chunk_data_length(); i++)
        {
            // This condition checks the iteration number with the vector data size of the client.
            // if client data size has reached then reading will be stopped
            if(server_track_client_data_size_before_reading < request.client_data_stream_size())
            {
                server_dummy_data_set.push_back(request.chunk_data_client_request(i));
                server_track_client_data_size_before_reading++;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    if(server_dummy_data_set.size() == request.client_data_stream_size())
    {
        std::cout << "Prepared data in server is identical to the data size transferred by client" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Caution !!! Data sample is mismatched");
    }

    // set proto message for server side
    response.set_server_data_stream_size(server_dummy_data_set.size());

    int64_t track_index = 0; // Tracks the current index of the server_dummy_data_set

    // Server starts streaming the data chunk by chunk to the client. Here, server is doing a dummy operation on clients data.
    // Here, it multiplies by 2 each data of the client.

    // This variable will track client side data size during write back to client
    uint32_t server_track_client_data_size_before_writing = 0;
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < request.required_chunk(); i++)
    {
        for(int64_t j = track_index * request.chunk_data_length(); j < request.chunk_data_length() + track_index * request.chunk_data_length(); j++)
        {
            if(server_track_client_data_size_before_writing < request.client_data_stream_size())
            {
                response.add_chunk_data_server_response(server_dummy_data_set[j] * 2);
                server_track_client_data_size_before_writing++;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        track_index++;
        stream->Write(response);

        // message field will be cleared after passing one chunk. It provides a fresh repeated field in the next iteration to pass a new chunk
        response.clear_chunk_data_server_response();
    }
}
```

**Any recommendation to upate the work, idea to add new feature/modify the algorithm/idea/work is highly appreciated.**